# BigQuery parquet file loads fails

Tags: google-bigquery

When I try to load manually or via airflow-apache script, bq loads fails with :  An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.

Command tested manually :

```
bq load --source_format=PARQUET test.hit_preprod_20170723 "gs://np-secor-v2/logs/hit/dt=2017-07-23/*"  
bq load --source_format=PARQUET prod.hit_prod_20171008 "gs://np-secor-v2/logs/hit/dt=2017-10-08/*"
```

This command work well since at least 6 month, we use it with a airflow script every days to load our logs.
I am sure that parquet files is not corrumpted cause I tested the command line with parquet that used to well be loaded.

Complete tracelog :

> Waiting on bqjob_r2fdc668026d40257_0000015fa1a46f06_1 ... (0s) Current
>   status: DONE     BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing
>   job 'omega-episode-702:bqjob_r2fdc668026d40257_0000015fa1a46f06_1': An
>   internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.

We use also JSON BigQuery loads and this command line worked well this morning on our production environment.

```
bq --project omega-episode-702 load --autodetect --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --schema=/data/nextperf/schema/event_schema.json prod.event_prod /data/nextperf/temp/event.json
```

Seems that the problem is coming from the PARQUET source.

Tested with bq version : 2.0.27, 2.0.25 and  2.0.24

Thanks,
Antoine

Comment: Please submit a bug report on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) instead, since this isn't an error that the general StackOverflow community can help with. Note that Parquet support is still in a closed alpha, but reporting bugs helps the BigQuery team to fix issues in order to open up the functionality to everyone.

Comment: Thx, I opened a ticket on the issue tracker as well. I will keep in touch about the fixe ( if there are one ).